# Is there a way to achieve a transparent basemap with px.density_mapbox?

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial, heatmap, plotly

I'm creating a heatmap with Plotly density_mapbox, and I need the background to be fully transparent so that the heatmap can be exported to geotiff and used as an overlay for an external map. The heatmap is created using the code below:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate dummy data
np.random.seed(42)
num_points = 1000
dummy_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'latitude': np.random.uniform(37.5, 38, num_points),
    'longitude': np.random.uniform(-122.5, -121.8, num_points),
    'predictions': np.random.uniform(0, 1, num_points)
})

# Create the density mapbox figure with dummy data
fig = px.density_mapbox(dummy_data, 
                        lat='latitude', lon='longitude', z='predictions', 
                        radius=20, 
                        center=dict(lat=dummy_data.latitude.mean(),
                                    lon=dummy_data.longitude.mean()),
                        zoom=3,
                        mapbox_style='open-street-map',
                        color_continuous_scale='viridis',
                        opacity=0.90)

# Show the figure
fig.show()
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve a transparent background? You can set the mapbox_style parameter to a white background like so, mapbox_style='white-bg'. However, I need it to be transparent.

**Solution**

1. Create a Custom Basemap with Mapbox:

Sign in or sign up for a Mapbox account (https://www.mapbox.com/).

Go to your Mapbox Studio (https://studio.mapbox.com/).
Create a new style or edit an existing one.

Customize your basemap by adding layers, changing colors, and adjusting the transparency as needed. To make a layer transparent, you can adjust its
opacity in the layer settings. I achieved this by adding a 'Background Layer' and setting the transparency to 100%.

Save the style.

2. Get Your Mapbox Access Token and your Style URL:

You'll need your Mapbox access token, which you can find if you select 'Share' in the top right corner, and you'll see them under 'Developer Resources'.

Update the code to include the following:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate dummy data
np.random.seed(42)
num_points = 1000
dummy_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'latitude': np.random.uniform(37.5, 38, num_points),
    'longitude': np.random.uniform(-122.5, -121.8, num_points),
    'predictions': np.random.uniform(0, 1, num_points)
})

# Create the density mapbox figure with dummy data
fig = px.density_mapbox(dummy_data, 
                        lat='latitude', lon='longitude', z='predictions', 
                        radius=20, 
                        center=dict(lat=dummy_data.latitude.mean(),
                                    lon=dummy_data.longitude.mean()),
                        zoom=3,
                        #mapbox_style='white-bg',
                        color_continuous_scale='viridis',
                        opacity=0.90)

# Define your Mapbox access token
mapbox_access_token = 'YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'

# Create the layout dictionary
layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=True,
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        style='mapbox://styles/your_username/your_style_id', # Replace with your Mapbox username and style ID
        center=dict(lat=dummy_data.latitude.mean(),
                    lon=dummy_data.longitude.mean()),
        zoom=3,
    ),
)

# Update the figure layout with the mapbox property
fig.update_layout(mapbox=layout.mapbox)

fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)", # Set the background color to transparent
                              coloraxis_showscale=False)  # Hide the color bar


# Display the figure
fig.show()
```

Comment: does this work: ```fig.update_layout({'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'})```?

Comment: No unfortunately not, I have given this a go but it gives me a white background. Thanks for the suggestion though! Much appreciated.